# I need to select the list of days (holidays) in the month and this random day like: 2 feb, 15 feb 5 mar etc. in the table calender in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show these give days as the holidays in the table calender.

```
TableCalendar(
                            calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                            daysOfWeekHeight: 20,
                            daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
                                weekdayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: lightColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                titleCentered: true,
                                formatButtonVisible: false,
                                leftChevronIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                                  color: buttoncolor,
                                ),
                                rightChevronIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                  color: buttoncolor,
                                ),
                                titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                )),
                            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                              markerSize: 40,
                              outsideDaysVisible: false,
                              todayTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: AppColor.transparent,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
                              selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: AppColor.orange,
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: AppColor.orange,
                                  width: 1,
                                  strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                                ),
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                            ),
                            rowHeight: 35,
                            firstDay: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 60)),
                            lastDay: DateTime.now(),
                            focusedDay: _currentDate,
                            onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                              if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedDate = selectedDay;
                                  _currentDate = focusedDay;
                                  controller.seeAttendance(context: context, selectedDate: _selectedDate);
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            holidayPredicate: (day) {
                              // Every 20th day of the month will be treated as a holiday
                              return day.weekday >= 6;
                            },

                            selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                              return isSameDay(_selectedDate, day);
                            },
                            onFormatChanged: (format) {
                              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _calendarFormat = format;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                              _currentDate = focusedDay;
                            },
                          ),

"attendance": [
        {
            "date": "2024-03-03"
        },
        {
            "date": "2024-03-07"
        },
        {
            "date": "2024-03-08"
        },
        {
            "date": "2024-03-11"
        },
        {
            "date": "2024-03-12"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please format your question/code properly. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you receiving any errors? [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.